# Sonata Page bundle varnish command exception

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Hello guys i have problem what i cant slove. I download sandbox Sonata Admin and try to install it. After setting parameters for db host, username and pass, media path and google auth i get this error for **sonata_page.varnish.command**.  Any solution how to slowe this problem?

`sonata_page.varnish.command: 'varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 {{ COMMAND }} "{{ EXPRESSION }}"'`

**Composer.json**

```
> {
>     "name": "sonata-project/sandbox",
>     "description": "Sonata Project's sandbox (with ecommerce bundles)",
> 
>     "license": "MIT",
> 
>     "autoload": {
>         "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
>     },
> 
>     "minimum-stability": "stable",
> 
>     "require": {
>         "php": ">=5.3.3",
> 
>         "twig/twig": "~1.12",
>         "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
> 
>         "symfony/symfony": "~2.5",
>         "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
>         "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
>         "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.3",
> 
>         "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
>         "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~2.3",
>         "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
> 
>         "jms/security-extra-bundle": "~1.5",
>         "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.4",
>         "jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.11",
> 
>         "doctrine/orm": "~2.4",
>         "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
>         "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
>         "doctrine/migrations": "~1.0@dev",
>         "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
>         "doctrine/data-fixtures": "~1.0@dev",
> 
>         "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.1",
> 
>         "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.1.4",
>         "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",
> 
>         "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
>         "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "~1@dev",
>         "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "~1@dev",
>         "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/media-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.1@dev",
>         "sonata-project/cache": "~1.0@dev",
>         "sonata-project/page-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/news-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
>         "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/exporter": "~1.3@dev",
> 
>         "sonata-project/timeline-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
>         "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-develop",
>         "sonata-project/comment-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
> 
>         "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
> 
>         "dflydev/markdown": "~1.0",
>         "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "~0.5",
>         "willdurand/faker-bundle": "~1.0",
> 
>         "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "v3.0.0-beta3",
>         "twbs/bootstrap": "v3.0.0",
> 
>         "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1",
>         "stephpy/TimelineBundle": "~2.0@dev",
>         "stephpy/timeline": "~1.0@dev",
> 
>         "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
>     },
> 
>     "require-dev": {
>         "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.2",
>         "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.0",
>         "behat/behat": "~2.4",
>         "behat/common-contexts": "*",
>         "behat/mink-extension": "~1.2",
>         "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.0",
>         "behat/mink": "~1.5",
>         "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "~1.1",
>         "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.1"
>     },
> 
>     "scripts": {
>         "post-install-cmd": [
>             "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
>             "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
>         ],
>         "post-update-cmd": [
>             "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
>             "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
>         ],
>         "post-create-project-cmd": [
>             "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
>             "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
>             "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
>             "php bin/load_data.php"
>         ]
>     },
> 
>     "config": {
>         "bin-dir": "bin"
>     },
> 
>     "extra": {
>         "symfony-app-dir": "app",
>         "symfony-web-dir": "web",
>         "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
>         "branch-alias": {
>             "dev-master": "2.3.x-dev"
>         },
>         "incenteev-parameters": [{
>             "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
>             "env-map": {
>                 "database_driver":   "DATABASE_DRIVER",
>                 "database_host":     "DATABASE_HOST",
>                 "database_name":     "DATABASE_NAME",
>                 "database_user":     "DATABASE_USER",
>                 "database_password": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
>                 "mailer_transport":  "MAILER_TRANSPORT",
>                 "mailer_host":       "MAILER_HOST",
>                 "mailer_user":       "MAILER_USER",
>                 "mailer_password":   "MAILER_PASSWORD",
> 
>                 "sonata_media.cdn.host": "SONATA_MEDIA_CDN_HOST"
>             }
>         }]
>     } }
```

**And my log output :**

```
        Installing sonata-project/sandbox (dev-2.3-develop 1726c8d127d6471920e8da635594157018fe852b)
      - Installing sonata-project/sandbox (dev-2.3-develop 2.3-develop)
        Cloning 2.3-develop

    Created project in /home/tirengarfio/workspace/sandbox
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
      - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing twig/twig (v1.15.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.1.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.3.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony/icu (v1.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.3.10)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.1.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.3.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master 0742fc7)
        Cloning 0742fc7167a4deedaabc8639849a3e71082999f1

      - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (dev-master 667f208)
        Cloning 667f20875f0dd3f3fce3e5a7d97cceac92a8e9d1

      - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (dev-master 83a910f)
        Cloning 83a910f62b01715f3ed7317f5a4996417a698177

      - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (v2.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/core-bundle (dev-master 077a62e)
        Cloning 077a62e8993eede6883f541b7b48b76a512ff3f0

      - Installing sonata-project/cache (dev-master 3bd8c26)
        Cloning 3bd8c266c6184ebcf82846d659292e9680b979eb

      - Installing sonata-project/block-bundle (dev-master 803a0b7)
        Cloning 803a0b7eb69279670adb12b2385df7b51c324df8

      - Installing knplabs/knp-menu (v1.1.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing knplabs/knp-menu-bundle (1.1.x-dev 2fecac0)
        Cloning 2fecac02614e5a006f674dd5dd754eeaeca060b9

      - Installing stephpy/timeline (dev-master b24dc45)
        Cloning b24dc45b2f39e9d935012b96bad253e580110df2

      - Installing stephpy/timelinebundle (dev-master b256014)
        Cloning b25601473a9087eb18f15ec9a11abf05094a77f6

      - Installing sonata-project/timeline-bundle (dev-master aca714e)
        Cloning aca714e0fbfe805a24b70ae00f756e8bd606d2a4

      - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.4.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpcollection/phpcollection (0.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/parser-lib (1.0.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/metadata (1.5.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/serializer (0.15.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/cg (1.0.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/aop-bundle (1.0.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/di-extra-bundle (1.4.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/serializer-bundle (0.13.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator (v1.0.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing willdurand/negotiation (1.2.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle (1.2.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v2.3.4)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle (dev-master 93f2f74)
        Cloning 93f2f74cc7ea4141a900464074af7c40e67d1e47

      - Installing dflydev/markdown (v1.0.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing nelmio/api-doc-bundle (2.5.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.3.4)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/jquery-bundle (1.8.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/exporter (1.3.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing twig/extensions (v1.0.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/admin-bundle (dev-master 4792ec7)
        Cloning 4792ec715210f61545e3002a191a6c22fe3b925d

      - Installing sonata-project/google-authenticator (1.0.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle (dev-master 63f2d9c)
        Cloning 63f2d9c99c94548fed1257c9503ac6efb39d73f0

      - Installing sonata-project/doctrine-extensions (1.0.2)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.2)
        Loading from cache

        Skipped installation of bin/doctrine for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
        Skipped installation of bin/doctrine.php for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
      - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v1.3.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/user-bundle (dev-master d045f27)
        Cloning d045f27153a3a5c75af967b3f51055d996ac069e

      - Installing sonata-project/notification-bundle (dev-master fa07c78)
        Cloning fa07c788692aa2d12b3ecc42e6d433c982b958f4

      - Installing kriswallsmith/buzz (v0.10)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing knplabs/gaufrette (v0.1.4)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing imagine/imagine (v0.5.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/media-bundle (dev-master c0f88b4)
        Cloning c0f88b4b05303d88ba6dc90dff8ab52185d8748f

      - Installing sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle (dev-master d108f68)
        Cloning d108f68b4911aed3e3708589abb8c2e64521c388

      - Installing sonata-project/comment-bundle (dev-master 2e68b7c)
        Cloning 2e68b7ca9edaa6754880b9d9133c515a4c9c5c53

      - Installing knplabs/knp-components (1.2.5)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (2.4.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/classification-bundle (dev-master 8f09ce6)
        Cloning 8f09ce69ce4b325cdcdb460d21cd40560ea6cc9b

      - Installing sonata-project/seo-bundle (dev-master 0ccc9f2)
        Cloning 0ccc9f2e36b467a9d4b7729ed075196b80376304

      - Installing sonata-project/intl-bundle (dev-master 0aa5e89)
        Cloning 0aa5e8997b0814986654a13569d532284451e9c3

      - Installing sonata-project/ecommerce (dev-develop 7a3a087)
        Cloning 7a3a08736c846b3989c41cf54b903f7ead361e58

      - Installing mopa/composer-bridge (v1.3.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing mopa/bootstrap-bundle (v3.0.0-beta3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing twbs/bootstrap (v3.0.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.3.9)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle (v1.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing behat/mink (v1.5.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing behat/gherkin (v2.3.5)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing behat/behat (v2.5.2)
        Loading from cache

        Skipped installation of bin/behat for package behat/behat: name conflicts with an existing file
      - Installing behat/mink-extension (v1.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing jms/security-extra-bundle (1.5.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.0.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.5)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing monolog/monolog (1.7.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.5.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v2.3.4)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing simplethings/entity-audit-bundle (v0.5.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing symfony-cmf/routing (1.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/cache-bundle (dev-master 2803d69)
        Cloning 2803d69b13e237b2de53076750e5c0df528727e8

      - Installing symfony-cmf/routing-bundle (1.1.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/page-bundle (dev-master a272911)
        Cloning a272911d24ef2141bc17cba3a3416917dad7b3fa

      - Installing knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle (1.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing egeloen/ckeditor-bundle (2.2.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/markitup-bundle (2.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing sonata-project/formatter-bundle (dev-master 3369c67)
        Cloning 3369c671fc43ec23013719d83bd681189357453b

      - Installing sonata-project/news-bundle (dev-master f69c9e2)
        Cloning f69c9e20bb0ea7bd782ff8cc726089e146b58780

      - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.3.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing willdurand/faker-bundle (1.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (1.2.3)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.5)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.2.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.3.4)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (1.2.16)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing phpunit/phpunit (3.7.32)
        Loading from cache

        Skipped installation of composer/bin/phpunit for package phpunit/phpunit: name conflicts with an existing file
      - Installing guzzle/common (v3.8.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing guzzle/stream (v3.8.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing guzzle/parser (v3.8.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing guzzle/http (v3.8.1)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing fabpot/goutte (v1.0.5)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing behat/mink-browserkit-driver (v1.1.0)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing behat/mink-goutte-driver (v1.0.9)
        Loading from cache

      - Installing instaclick/php-webdriver (1.0.17)
        Loading from cache

        Skipped installation of bin/webunit for package instaclick/php-webdriver: name conflicts with an existing file
      - Installing behat/mink-selenium2-driver (v1.1.1)
        Loading from cache

    kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
    kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
    kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
    kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
    doctrine/data-fixtures suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (For loading MongoDB ODM fixtures)
    doctrine/data-fixtures suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (For loading PHPCR ODM fixtures)
    sonata-project/cache suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (PHPCR ODM support)
    sonata-project/cache suggests installing ext-memcached (Caching with ext/memcached)
    sonata-project/cache suggests installing predis/predis (Install redis php)
    knplabs/knp-menu suggests installing pimple/pimple (for the built-in implementations of the menu provider and renderer provider)
    knplabs/knp-menu suggests installing silex/silex (for the integration with your silex application)
    stephpy/timeline suggests installing predis/predis (Redis PHP client library)
    stephpy/timeline suggests installing pimple/pimple (Use ServiceLocator)
    stephpy/timeline suggests installing ext-redis (Redis C extension for PHP)
    stephpy/TimelineBundle suggests installing snc/redis-bundle (Use redis driver)
    stephpy/TimelineBundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (Use doctrine ODM driver)
    friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle suggests installing ornicar/akismet-bundle (Integrate Akismet for spamdetection.)
    sonata-project/exporter suggests installing propel/propel1 (~1.6)
    sonata-project/admin-bundle suggests installing jms/translation-bundle (Extract message keys from Admins)
    friendsofsymfony/user-bundle suggests installing willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior (Needed when using the propel implementation)
    sonata-project/notification-bundle suggests installing guzzle/guzzle (3.*)
    sonata-project/notification-bundle suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (2.0.*)
    sonata-project/notification-bundle suggests installing liip/monitor-bundle (~1.0)
    knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle (*)
    knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing dropbox-php/dropbox-php (to use the Dropbox adapter)
    knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php (to use the Amazon S3 adapter)
    knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing ext-mongo (*)
    imagine/imagine suggests installing ext-imagick (to use the Imagick implementation)
    imagine/imagine suggests installing ext-gmagick (to use the Gmagick implementation)
    sonata-project/media-bundle suggests installing liip/imagine-bundle (~0.9)
    sonata-project/media-bundle suggests installing amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php (~1.5)
    sonata-project/media-bundle suggests installing rackspace/php-opencloud (~1.6)
    sonata-project/media-bundle suggests installing tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-mediabundle (~1.0)
    knplabs/knp-components suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (to allow usage pagination with Doctrine ODM MongoDB)
    knplabs/knp-components suggests installing ruflin/Elastica (to allow usage pagination with ElasticSearch Client)
    knplabs/knp-components suggests installing propel/propel1 (to allow usage pagination with Propel ORM)
    knplabs/knp-components suggests installing solarium/solarium (to allow usage pagination with Solarium Client)
    mopa/bootstrap-bundle suggests installing mopa/bootstrap-sandbox-bundle (~2.3)
    mopa/bootstrap-bundle suggests installing craue/formflow-bundle (~2.0)
    mopa/bootstrap-bundle suggests installing jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap (dev-master)
    gedmo/doctrine-extensions suggests installing doctrine/mongodb (>=1.0.1)
    gedmo/doctrine-extensions suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (>=1.0.0-BETA7)
    stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (to use the MongoDB ODM extensions)
    behat/mink suggests installing behat/mink-zombie-driver (fast and JS-enabled headless driver for any app (requires node.js))
    behat/behat suggests installing behat/symfony2-extension (for integration with Symfony2 web framework)
    behat/behat suggests installing behat/yii-extension (for integration with Yii web framework)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing mlehner/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
    monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
    monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
    sonata-project/cache-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-bundle (PHPCR ODM support)
    sonata-project/cache-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (PHPCR ODM support)
    sonata-project/cache-bundle suggests installing ext-memcached (Caching with ext/memcached)
    sonata-project/cache-bundle suggests installing predis/predis (Install redis php)
    symfony-cmf/routing-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (To enable support for the PHPCR ODM documents)
    symfony-cmf/routing-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-bundle (To enable support for the PHPCR ODM documents)
    symfony-cmf/routing-bundle suggests installing symfony-cmf/content-bundle (To optionally use the configured value for 'content_basepath' from the CoreBundle)
    symfony-cmf/routing-bundle suggests installing symfony-cmf/core-bundle (For compatibility with Symfony 2.2 and easier configuration)
    symfony-cmf/routing-bundle suggests installing sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle (To provide an admin interface for the PHPCR ODM documents)
    knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle suggests installing ext-sundown (to use optional support for php-sundown extension instead of php implementation)
    egeloen/ckeditor-bundle suggests installing helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle (Allows to use the elfinder as CKEditor file manager)
    phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.0.5)
    phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (>=1.1.0,<1.2.0)
    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
    Some parameters are missing. Please provide them.
    database_driver (pdo_mysql): 
    database_host (127.0.0.1): 
    database_name (sonata_sandbox): 
    database_user (sonata): ******
    database_password (sonata): *****
    mailer_transport (smtp): 
    mailer_host (localhost): 
    mailer_user (null): 
    mailer_password (null): 
    locale (en): es
    secret (ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt): 
    sonata_admin.title ('Sonata Project'): 
    sonata_admin.logo_title (/bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png): 
    sonata_news.blog_title ('My Awesome Blog'): 
    sonata_news.blog_link ('http://awesome-blog.ltd'): 
    sonata_news.blog_description ('My Awesome blog description'): 
    sonata_news.salt (ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt): 
    sonata_news.comment.emails ([mail@example.org]): 
    sonata_news.comment.email_from (no-reply@example.org): 
    sonata_media.cdn.host (/uploads/media): 
    sonata_user.google_authenticator.server (demo.sonata-project.org): 
sonata_page.varnish.command ('if [ ! -r "/etc/varnish/secret" ]; then echo "
D ERROR :/"; else varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 {{ COM
 }} "{{ EXPRESSION }}"; fi;'):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sonata\2\sandbo
ndor\sonata-project\page-bundle\Admin\SharedBlockAdmin.php on line 72
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache h
ing the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/commit/a2d83e6c02f566222bc04827885566d981270176

Next time, report it to github ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same Problème here since two days...
Obviously the issue comes with the last version: see https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/commit/bf48498c36dc4e09f8e80434f4b2d8caa045b956

I rolled back manually the change on line 72 as a workaround and it did the trick.

Or

An even better solution was to change the version of the PageBundle to "sonata-project/page-bundle" : "~2.2", in the composer.json (instead of the  "dev-master" one)